# Mount exteral drive on startup RPi 2

Tags: raspbian, mount, fstab, systemd

So, I'm trying to mount an external USB drive to /home on a Raspberry Pi 2. I thought mounting an external drive upon startup would be easy. I added a line to /etc/fstab for the new device and rebooted but I immediately got a failure message. it says "Unable to resolve 'UUID=......' and puts me in a maintenance shell. It's absolutely the correct UUID. I can mount the drive from the maintenance shell with "mount /home" no problem. What seems to be happening is that systemd times out before the external drive becomes available.

From reading a bit of the man page I thought I might be able to add "x-systemd.device-timeout=10" to the mount options in the fstab file, but subsequently trying to run "mount /home" I get the following error:

> [  370.649941] EXT4-fs (sda1): Unrecognized mount option
>   "x-systemd.device-timeout=10" or missing value

I'm fairly sure I need to add some sort of rule to systemd that tells it to wait on my external drive, but I have no idea how to do that and google didn't seem to turn up any good results.

I've spent a few hours trying to figure this out and nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

By the way, here's my /etc/fstab file:

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
UUID=9bbf04b2-d381-41a6-b29b-6220c4048911 /home   ext4    defaults        0       2
#UUID=9bbf04b2-d381-41a6-b29b-6220c4048911 /home   ext4    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=10        0       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel a little bit foolish. Systemd wasn't the problem, it was the solution! I thought systemd was the default for raspbian. It is not! I followed [this](http://blog.higgsboson.tk/2012/09/19/systemd-on-raspbian/) tutorial to install it and now everything works fine. It's worth noting that after the change my Pi no longer booted into a console so I ran "sudo update-rc.d -f lightdm remove" to change it back.

Answer (score 3):

I did it with these instructions and it worked without problems.
http://www.modmypi.com/blog/how-to-mount-an-external-hard-drive-on-the-raspberry-pi-raspian
I hope this helps.

Comment: That's essentially what I've done already. The only real difference is the sixth field is a 0 in that tutorial. I just tried changing it and it still doesn't mount, although it doesn't kick me into a maintenance shell anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Looking trough man fstab i see:

```
   The mountall(8) program that mounts filesystem during boot also recognises additional options that the ordinary mount(8) tool does not.  These are: ``bootwait'' which can be applied to remote filesys‐
   tems  mounted  outside of /usr or /var, without which mountall(8) would not hold up the boot for these; ``nobootwait'' which can be applied to non-remote filesystems to explicitly instruct mountall(8)
   not to hold up the boot for them; ``optional'' which causes the entry to be ignored if the filesystem type is not known at boot time; and ``showthrough'' which  permits  a  mountpoint  to  be  mounted
   before its parent mountpoint (this latter should be used carefully, as it can cause boot hangs).
```

And as such probably adding the option bootwait will do the trick

Comment: That sounded promising, but still didn't work. I get the same error